# NestJS / Swagger - Can't Import the Module

Tags: typescript, npm, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I am creating a boilerplate nestjs app. I want to add [@nestjs/swagger](http://@nestjs/swagger)
 to project but getting import error. Can't import the module.

```
npm install --save @nestjs/swagger@4.8.0 --force
```

I tried above command after getting errors. Deleted and reinstalled the node_modules. Nothing is working.

```
src/main.ts:2:44 - error TS1005: 'from' expected.

2 import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule }  '@nestjs/swagger'
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[7:47:36 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

Here is the main.ts file

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule }  '@nestjs/swagger'
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('NestJS Middleware Test')
    .setDescription('Implemenet a simple requst interceptor for authorization')
    .setVersion('0.0.1')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options)
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document)

  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: The keyword `from` is missing. It should be `import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from '@nestjs/swagger'`

Comment: OMG. I should delete the question. Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong importing syntax. Even in the error message, you can see `'from' expected`.

The correct way to import is

```
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger'
```

Comment: VSCode sometimes doesnt work well. All the imports was okay until now but today....

Comment: Hmm. That's so strange. Do you mean that it was imported automatically?